# android:imeOptions="actionNext" in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, imeoptions

I have a recyclerView with edittexts. I want to implement `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` for all editttexts
 in recyclerView, however it is working only for views which are in the same viewHolder. But I want to do it for all my recyclerView. How can I do that ?